# Issues with scraping HTML page (SEC Annual Report) using scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I apologize in advance if I'm making any obvious mistakes, I'm new to Python and Scrapy.

I am trying to scrape Apple's 10k form ([link to form](https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm)). Specifically, i'm just trying to scrape a single table located on Part II, item 5, called "Purchases of Equity Securities by the Issuer and Affiliated Purchasers".

My code is:

```
import scrapy


class AaplSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "aapl"
    allowed_domains = ["www.sec.gov"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm"]


    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('(//table)[13]/tbody/tr'):
            yield {
            'Periods' : row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first(),
            'Total Number of Shares Purchased': row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first(),
            'Average Price Paid Per Share' : row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

However I can't seem to get scrapy to find this table, even though I can correctly select it using this xpath expression in chrome ((//table)[13]/tbody). Is this table being blocked somehow or am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that are keeping you from parsing the information you want.

1. The url that you are attempting to scrape doesn't actually contain the content that you are seeking.  It is rendered via javascript after the initial page is loaded.  The spinning loading icon that is shown when you refresh the page is a one giveaway of this fact, but another is if click `view page source` in the context menu, it will show you the html for the url, and it will be very obvious.
2. For some reason that is unknown to me, certain web browsers inject html tags  into the document body when viewing the page contents in the dev tools `inspect` pane.  In your case the `tbody` element doesn't actually exist in the page source html.

The solution to the first issue is to simply use the url for the content that you actually want, which can be found in my example below, and the solution for the second issue is to omit the `tbody` portion of your xpath expressions.

For example:

```
import scrapy


class AaplSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "aapl"
    allowed_domains = ["www.sec.gov"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm"]


    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('(//table)[13]/tr'):
            yield {
            'Periods' : row.xpath('./td[1]//text()').extract_first(),
            'Total Number of Shares Purchased': row.xpath('./td[3]//text()').extract_first(),
            'Average Price Paid Per Share' : row.xpath('./td[7]//text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

OUTPUT:

```
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm> (referer: None)
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': None, 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': None, 'Average Price Paid Per Share': None}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'Periods', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': 'Total Number', 'Average Price Paid Per Share': 'Total Number of Shares'}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'June 26, 2022 to July 30, 2022:', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': None, 'Average Price Paid Per Share': None}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'Open market and privately negotiated purchases', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': '41,690\xa0', 'Average Price Paid Per Share': '145.91\xa0'}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': None, 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': None, 'Average Price Paid Per Share': None}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'July 31, 2022 to August 27, 2022:', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': None, 'Average Price Paid Per Share': None}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'Open market and privately negotiated purchases', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': '54,669\xa0', 'Average Price Paid Per Share': '168.29\xa0'}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': None, 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': None, 'Average Price Paid Per Share': None}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'August 28, 2022 to September 24, 2022:', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': None, 'Average Price Paid Per Share': None}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'Open market and privately negotiated purchases', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': '63,813\xa0', 'Average Price Paid Per Share': '155.59\xa0'}
2023-03-20 23:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm>
{'Periods': 'Total', 'Total Number of Shares Purchased': '160,172\xa0', 'Average Price Paid Per Share': None}
```